# How can I convert datetime format in R to be read for a Time-Series prediction model?

Tags: python, r, datetime, time-series

I have a financial stock-exchange dataset of the following kind, using dput(head(data3, 7))

```
structure(list(X = 0:6, 
               Unnamed..0 = 0:6, 
               date = c("2022-01-04", "2022-01-04", "2022-01-04", "2022-01-04", "2022-01-04", "2022-01-04", "2022-01-04"), 
               time = c(7.089, 8.619, 8.908, 9.588, 10.744, 10.931, 10.931), 
               price = c(263, 259, 259, 260, 258, 258, 259), qty = c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L), 
              datetime = c("2022-01-04 8:00:07.089000", "2022-01-04 8:00:08.619000", "2022-01-04 8:00:08.908000", "2022-01-04 8:00:09.588000", "2022-01-04 8:00:10.744000", "2022-01-04 8:00:10.931000", "2022-01-048:00:10.931000")), 
      row.names = c(NA, 7L), 
      class = "data.frame")
```

I am trying to apply an ARIMA model to it. The columns Date and Time, for each day, uniquely identify the changes in the price of a commodity for every second of each day, for months ahead. The diagram is just shortened tremendously.

In this case, How can I change this date and time to be effectively used by an ARIMA model in R/Python?

Comment: Help us help you. Please remove the image and paste the result of `dput(head(df, 7))` so we can copy and paste your data and try some possible solutions.

Comment: I've just arranged this. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: the time in your data, ¿is it seconds, hours, minutes?

Comment: It is in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I'll attempt to solve this with the help of some packages.

First lubridate to convert character dates to actual dates:

```
library(lubridate)

# assuming it is in Year - month - day. If its Year - day - month, use ydm(data3$date)
data3$date = ymd(data3$date)
```

Now we need to be able to **observe** that indeed we are adding fractions of seconds, so I'll change the options (by default only whole seconds are shown):

```
options(digits.secs = 6)
```

Then I'll add the seconds to the date and create a new variable:

```
data3$dateTime = data3$date + dseconds(data3$time)
```

Here `dseconds` is a function of package lubridate for durations in seconds (see `?dseconds`).

Now to convert that to a time series, I'd go with package `zoo`, as it allows you to use irregular time series:

```
library(zoo)

newTS = zoo(data3$price, order.by = data3$dateTime)
```

**Please notice that with your supplied data, zoo will complain about not unique indexes**. That's because the last two observations share the same date and time (wich may be a mistake?).

You can then perform any operation on the new time series.